# Jquery Colorbox Next and Previous buttons not working after updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, colorbox, caroufredsel

I'm using Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox and recently updated it from version 1.3.20 to version 1.5.10. Now the Previous and Next buttons are not working.

The existing colorbox object is configured like this,

```
$(".inline").colorbox({
                    arrowKey: false,
                    reload: false,
                    customClick: true,
                    customTyping: false,
                    width: '655px',
                    loop: false,
                    scrolling: false,
                    inline: true,
                    rel: 'inline',
                    href: $(this).attr('href'),
                    click: $(this).click(),
                    current: 'Item {current} of {total}'
                });
```

$(".inline") is an array of anchor elements.

```
  <div id="foo" data-bind="with: carouselItems">
            <!-- ko foreach:items -->
            <div class="carouselItem">
                <a class='inline' data-bind="attr: { href: '#BlogCarousel' }, click: $root.load">
                    <input id="carouselElements" type="hidden" data-bind="value: Id" />
                    <img data-bind="attr: { src: PreviewImageUrl }" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```

Should the configurations for Next and Previous buttons be changed? 
Seems like reload, customClick, customTyping, click properties are no longer available in the Colorbox plugin. What are the alternatives for those properties?

Comment: You better post some html or if you can setup a jsfiddle

Comment: Need to see some html.. possibly more info on what jquery version etc too..

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Without a reproducible example, you are throwing away your bounty points. Please show your HTML or, preferably, a JSFiddle of the problem.

Comment: The scenario is the Colorbox opens when click one item in a carousel plugin called carouFredSel. In that event it retrieves data from a signalR hub. When click the Next/Previous it's supposed to retrieve data of the next element in the carousel. This carousel items are binded as a knockout object. The point is this worked perfectly fine until I upgrade the Colobox plugin. It seems the Next/Previous buttons click events are not triggering. Using jquery-1.11.1 version

Comment: Try removing `click: $(this).click()`

Comment: I tried removing click property. Still not working

Comment: Seems like reload, customClick, customTyping, click properties are no longer available in the Colorbox plugin. What are the alternatives for those properties?

Comment: providing a fiddle will help you get better answer.

Answer (score 1):

reading the doc it says when

```
arrowKey: false
```

deactivates the arrows, so set

```
arrowKey: true
```

reading the changelog, maybe this is an interesting part :

```
Version 1.4.0 - 2013/2/12

Better accessibility:
   Replaced div controls with buttons
```

so you may change your selectors in your knockout or whatsoever click triggering code ?!

Comment: you should rather post some error-message and your knockout code, pretty sure just the selectors changed ;-D

Comment: Both previous div and recent button have same ids (#cboxPrevious and #cboxNext). This next/previous click triggering code it built-in in the plugin. I haven't code it. I only provided $(".inline") - an array of anchor elements with some attributes to colorbox. Thanks again